# Fetching the IP address using MicroPython

Tags: python, networking, micropython

Trying to use pybricks-micropython

Want to get the localhost name/IP address. Can do in CPython with this code... but doesn't seem to be an equivalent I can find in MicroPython?

```
hostName = socket.gethostname()
hostIPA = socket.gethostbyname(hostName)
```

Searching on the net, but cannot seem to find anything I can use?

Comment: There is [ifconfig](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/network.html#network.AbstractNIC.ifconfig)

Comment: Sadly network library isn't called network on Pybricks it seems, nothing of that name exists.

Comment: ... to what end?

Comment: I running a server on the brick. I need the IP address so that I can bind to it. Shall I post the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special Thanks to David Lechner who pointed me in the right direction and gave 95% of this answer.

```
os.popen('hostname -I'.read().strip().split(" "))
```

Gives you the IP4 address!